# Asp.net Chart control in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, chart-web-part, chart

Can anyone help me to save the chart control temporary image files on SharePoint 2010 document library/picture library. Actually in my standalone environment the webpart is working fine when using c:\TempImageFiles folder for storing the temp image files. But my client's production environment is having more servers with load balancing and the webpart is not working as expected in place of showing charts webpart shows a "X" sign on the top of image/chart. I used `chart.ImageLocation = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["TempImage"].DefaultViewUrl + "/ChartPic_#SEQ(200,30)";` 
with allow unsafe update as true, but without success. It is throwing javascript errors as `Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8080\siteURL\TempImage\Forms\AllItems.aspx\ChartPic_000001.png'.` Any help in this regard will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

When using Load balanced environment the request might not go to the same server where actually the chart image is created. One way to resolve this is setting "**IP Affinity**" on your load balancer, that shall direct the ongoing requests from a client to the same server where it furnished preceeding requests. Another way is use a UNC path shared across all servers, but that may hinder due to security restrictions in production environment.

Update : @DeepakSemwal , I did not do it myself, but can give a possible way of doing it, looking at the links you referred.
Web.config setting.

```
<appSettings> 
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;dir=[you doclib url];"/> 
</appSettings>
```

you might need to give necessary permission on this lib(probably to the 'Network service' or ASPNET_user).

Set chart properties like that (or may be programmatically set it)

```
 <asp:Chart ID="chart" runat="server" Width="500" Height="350"          
     ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" 
     ImageType="Png">    ... 
 </asp:Chart>
```

while setting the image location in code like

```
string newUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url +"/"+ [doclib].RootFolder.Url; // where doclib is your imageslibrary 
chart.ImageLocation =  newUrl ;
```

See if it can work for you.

Comment: Hi Furqan, thanks for your quick rpl.. is it possible to store the chart control's temporary images in SharePoint document library/ Picture Library ? If yes then Hows ?

Comment: @Deepak IMHO, it might not be possible.

Comment: Hi Furqan, Please have a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079113/asp-net-chart-control-in-sharepoint-2010), Roman putting his inputs to save the image in document library.

Comment: Hi Furqan, Manish Joshi also describing to save the temp images in document library [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b3ce497a-ac72-4dbb-9e64-258829fb3972/?prof=required), but when I am trying the same getting javascript errors. Can you help?

Comment: @DeepakSemwal , I updated a answer based on the links you pointed. Though I am not sure 100% for this to work, lets just give it a try.

Comment: Hi Furqan, I tried to change the settings as you mentioned but still the error message appears: `Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: http://sp2010/Chart/ChartPic_000001.png is not a valid virtual path.`

Comment: @DeepakSemwal, Is the chart file created in that path or not ?I mean are you able to save the chart in the library first?

Comment: Nopes no charts in the document library.

Comment: @DeepakSemwal, can you show what you put in these settings `value="storage=file;dir=[you doclib url];`

Comment: Hi Furkan, when we use `ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"` that time chart control does't look for the Handler settings. I tried a lot of combinations in the web.config settings. currently `<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=30;deleteafterservicing=false" />`. If I change the dir value as you specifying document library url([http:\\sp2010\Chart\]) and use http handler gets `
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration [http:\\sp2010\Chart\].`

Comment: @Furkan: I had a discussion with my manager. He had asked if you would like to work as a paid consultant for this task? If yes, please let me know, I will pass on the word to them.

Comment: @DeepakSemwal, I am sorry I am already having loads of work, so cannot manage to work as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a answer for my query, to store the chart images in SharePoint document library we need to map a document library to a hard disc drive (as I did z:) and then set the chart image handler as: `<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file; timeout=3600;  url=Z:\;"/>` for this to work porperly we also need to change the script manager's async postback timeout property to 3600 as `AsyncPostBackTimeOut="3600"`. The process is taking around 3 minutes (as it first creating the chart images in document library and then downloading those) in my environment which is bit high for the users to wait that much long :( so again searching for some methods that can make the process faster. Hope this can help someone.